# Making 'OR' Queries in Google App Engine Data Model

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I want to make a query like this "Select name from Person where Address="" OR age="" ". Is that possible in the GAE model. All things include AND closure and not OR. How can i do that with JDO/JPA, Objectify. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "OR" operation on the datastore.  You must do two separate queries and find the intersection in your own code.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html

Comment: Some more discussion here, http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/8bdfd6633191da04

Comment: I guess this is the easiest way to do it. 2 queries then put result in a set. Thx for your help

Comment: I know this is an old post, but for those who stumble upon this....  it seems like a convoluted workaround in *some* situations is to use custom conditions (see https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Queries).  You could create an index using a PojoIf and put the OR inside the PojoIf. However, to use this index, seems like you'd need to use an additional filter or order on one of those two fields in the query. Also, any additional query that used those fields for filtering or ordering might use that index.  Probably more trouble than it's worth but just a thought.

Comment: @rimsky It seems like a lot of work. I wonder why a simple or is not present. Doing two query for some might become a big problem for some.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Anyone who is having difficulties with GAE datastore model to have a look at this video. It explains how it works, then you will understand why the limitations exists

http://sites.google.com/site/io/under-the-covers-of-the-google-app-engine-datastore