# Add field to filter: a boolean OR for Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying to build a query statement that returns results if a username matches a lastname OR a firstname in the database, i.e.

("lastname", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, username) OR ("firstname", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, username)

but I don't know the syntax.  Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

(Sorry, I know I'm not supposed to ask basic programming questions here, and I see related posts for Magento (addfieldtofilter), but not for GAE.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Making 'OR' Queries in Google App Engine Data Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393571/making-or-queries-in-google-app-engine-data-model) top answer concisely and correctly puts it, "There is no `OR` operation on the datastore. You must do two separate queries and find the intersection in your own code". (Well, should be **union**, not **intersection**, of course:-).

That particular question mentioned `objectify`, but, it's not about objectify -- just a limitation of how the datastore works. (Even the `!=` and `IN` operators, which appear to work, are an optical illusion, implemented on the application side of things with two or more separate queries followed by taking their union in memory. In App Engine **python**, the `ndb` datastore access layer *does* offer an `ndb.OR` operator -- but *that*, too, is simulated at application level (from the datastore's viewpoint it's multiple queries -- ndb's app level code then does an in-memory union).

I guess somebody could similarly build a datastore access framework for Java (e.g fork and enrich `objectify`) for the specific purpose of simulating `OR` like `ndb` does, but to the best of my knowledge, nobody has thought that worth the bother (I find it hard to disagree -- even though `ndb` was designed and implemented by Guido van Rossum, inventor and leader of Python, when he worked at Google specifically on App Engine, so his engineering judgment may be more worthy of trust, than mine:-).

Comment: Thank you!!!!! Mentally, it seems odd to me not to be able to add filters to the query, but the solution is clear. Thank you!